# How imports of static libraries work in Java / Spring?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am experimenting MockMvc of Spring framework. To call perform method of MockMvc I would need to have an import as following

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
```

**Partial code**

```
 this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(view().name("homePage"));
```

I know get method is static, but it is the first time that I see import has static keyword. Is anyone able to explain this to me? why static keyword is required? why just method is imported? I am a bit confused with this.

Comment: [An almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209169/static-import-in-java) got closed in the past.  Though I don't really know why.  (It has good answers nevertheless.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "static" modifier after "import" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162187/what-does-the-static-modifier-after-import-mean)

Comment: it's shorter then writing `this.mockMvc.perform(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/"))` with no import :)

Comment: @zapl Question in Jan '13 gets closed as “not a real question”, question in Jul '13 scores +141.  I see…

Comment: @5gon12eder yeah, it's rather arbitrary sometimes. Especially short questions with short answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's importing the static `get()` method in the `MockMvcRequestBuilders` class. This means you can call it directly (without doing `MockMvcRequestBuilders.get()`.)

This applies to any static method or field in another class - it's not specifically a spring / MockMvc thing. Likewise you don't *need* the import per-se, it just provides a shorthand notation.